# How can I reach the presentViewController method in my ViewController with this hierarchy? VC -> TableView -> Cell -> Button

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, io

How can I reach the presentViewController method in my ViewController with this hierarchy?

```
UIViewController -> UITableView -> UITableViewCustomCell -> UIButton
```

UIButton triggers **foo**, and **foo** is inside UITableViewCustomCell

```
- (void)foo
{
    TWNumericKeyboardController *vc =
       (TWNumericKeyboardController *) [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NumericKeyboard"];
}
```

From here, I need to reach my ViewController, so that I can call presentViewController.
How can I do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't put the button's action in the controller that needs to do the presentation?

Comment: ... I really have to get some rest. Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest putting the button's action method in the controller that needs to do the presentation. Depending on your current design, this might be a bit of work right now to set up, but I think it will pay off in understandability and flexibility in the future.